# Simplest way to automate starting of EC2 daily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I've been looking into ways to have an EC2 start daily at a certain time, and there are many ways, but none seem particularly simple - I am after the simplest way (including GUI based ways). All I want is for an EC2 (with a specific AMI) to start at a set time each day (it will run a boot script and terminate itself once it's done - I do not need help with these parts though).

So my question is, how can I automate the starting of an EC2 daily?

#### Backgroud info

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/867643/474272) excellent answer, shows a way to use cloudformation / instance scheduler. I am open to using these services, however, they might be overkill for the simple use case I have. Also, that answer says the documentation is not well written, which I think is true for users wanting to get started quickly and who don't care so much about region and many other options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a Lambda function to start your EC2 plus use CloudWatch Events for scheduling: [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success using an autoscaling group with scheduled scaling actions.
I have one scaling action to set the desired count to 1, then I have a second action to set the desired count to 0 a little before the first scaling action.
The instance will need to terminate itself without replacement in the autoscaling group.

The second scaling action acts as a failsafe to remove instances where the job has failed to terminate the instance.